# Place of continuously as an adverb

Tags: adverbs

As far as I know we can't use an adverb before the objects. Like that.

I painted carefully the house [incorrect]
I carefully painted the house [correct]
I painted the house carefully [correct]

But in case of continuously I saw these following examples on the Cambridge dictionary.

You can't work continuously for six hours without a break!
The teachers speak continuously throughout the class.

What is the difference between continuously and other adverbs??

Answer (score 1):

The difference between your two examples isn't the choice of adverb, but the fact that your first example has a transitive verb and a direct object. You shouldn't put an adverb between a verb and its direct object.

Note that we can use "carefully" in your second example sentences:

> You can't work carefully for six hours without a break!"
>   The teachers speak carefully throughout the class."